# Sliding menu Android

Tags: android, menu, fragment, android-tabhost, sliding

I have an app that is using tabHost menu and I need to change it, because the menu items is growing and they don't fit in the current menu. My classes are extending FragmentActivity, I want to know if is possible to use Sliding Menu with them or I will need to change all classes to extend Fragment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) in your project, you can implement sliding menu in your `FragmentActivity`, **as you want**.

### step1. new SlidingMenu and attach to your activity.

Refer to [How to Integrate this Library into Your Projects](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu#how-to-integrate-this-library-into-your-projects):

> You can wrap your Activities in a SlidingMenu by constructing it programmatically (
>
> `menu = new SlidingMenu(Context context)`) and then calling
>
> `menu.attachToActivity(Activity activity, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW | SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT)`.
>
> `SLIDING_WINDOW` will include the Title/ActionBar in the content section of the SlidingMenu, while
>   `SLIDING_CONTENT` does not. 
>   You can check it out in the example app **AttachExample Activity**.

### step2. Then implement a `SampleListFragment` which represent your menu, and add to your activity.

define a fragment container layout `fragment_menu.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

call `menu.setMenu(R.layout.fragment_menu);` **to add the fragment container view to your activity**,

Lastly, **add your `SampleListFragment` to your activity's fragment manager**:

```
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new SampleListFragment())
    .commit();
```

---

In this way, you got a sliding menu in your fragment activity.
That's all.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't try, but it's the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think in second fragment when you open third fragment if you add transaction in back state like
 **`transaction.addToBackStack(null);`**
 than remove this line of code

if problem than show your navigation code from second to third fragment

Comment: Sorry, I guess you didn't understand my question, I want to know if it's possible to use Sliding Menu with FragmentActivity instead of Fragment